# How do I align verticallly, centered and to the left in Boostrap's grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to align this Back button in a grid. I can only get to align to the top or center. Could someone provide an example on how to do this?

thx

```
    <!-- Action bar clone -->
    <div id="header">
      <div class="col-xs-12 navbar-inverse navbar-top">
          <div class="row" role="nav" id="topNav">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="glyphiconHeaderBack"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 text-center glyphiconHeader"><h1>Test Header</h1></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box bootstrap doesn't have a great vertical align option.  In the past what I have done (and from most of what I've seen out there) is using padding to align items where you want.  Adding some onto your back element aligns it much better for me.

```
padding:24px;
```

View it in action here: http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/xEYOzy